# Looping over a list of filenames and appending them together in Python

Tags: python, pandas, append, filenames

So far I have a list of files that start with the same part of the filename so I want to wildcard and get a list of all of the filenames in the directory that start with the same part of the filename and then append all of the files together so that it is just one big file. I know I need to import glob. So here is what I have so far.

```
import glob

filename = glob.glob('1511**.mnd')
data_nov15_hereford = pd.DataFrame()
list = []

for i in filename:
  f_nov15_hereford = pd.read_csv(i, skiprows = 33, sep='\s+',chunksize=30)
  list.append(f_nov15_hereford)
  data_nov15_hereford = pd.concat(list)
  data_nov15_hereford = data_nov15_hereford.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Is there an easier or better way to do this that actually works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import glob

filename = glob.glob('1511**.mnd')
data_nov15_hereford = pd.DataFrame()
frames = []

for i in filename:
    f_nov15_hereford = pd.read_csv(i, skiprows = 33, sep='\s+')
    frames.append(f_nov15_hereford)
data_nov15_hereford = pd.concat(frames)
data_nov15_hereford = data_nov15_hereford.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
# save to csv
data_nov15_hereford.to_csv(filename)
```

---

- Don't call `pd.concat()` inside the `for-loop`. Doing so is largely wasted effort, since

  ```
  data_nov15_hereford = pd.concat(list)
  ```

  assigns a new value to `data_nov15_hereford` on each iteration of the loop.
- Avoid naming variables `list`, since `list` is a built-in Python class. Assigning a particular list to `list` may cause surprising, hard-to-find errors later on in innocuous-looking code like `x = list(...)` (which would raise a `TypeError: 'list' object not callable` error.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am now getting an error though: TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object

Comment: My mistake. When you use `chunksize=30`, `pd.read_csv` returns an iterator which yields DataFrames, not a DataFrame itself. Since `pd.concat` expects a list of DataFrames, `chunksize=30` should be removed.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I suppose the problem is that I wanted to keep chunksize = 30 because for each file that I am looping through I want it to chunksize each one every 30 lines (because of the way the raw data looks with headers and such) so if I get rid of that it won't read nicely. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry! My mistake, I got rid of chunksize and it actually reads just fine! Thanks so much, it works!